# Statistical Significance Testing for 2D spatial field

Tags: statistical-significance, forecasting, resampling

I am running permutations of the Weather Research and Forecasting model and want to determine the statistical significance of various parameters versus a control run with none of these options set. There are 12 permutation members, of which an ensemble of three WRF runs have been performed for each using varying initialization seeds to generate perturbations of the data (36 total runs). My data are output in netCDF files (3 & 4 dimensional), but the fields I would like to test are two-dimensional spatial data (E.g. Precipitation).

Currently I have a setup to run the Fraction Skill Score (I calculate these scores in python for varying window sizes between 1 and 1000) of each member versus a verification set and am comparing the differences in these scores, however to improve the results of my research, I would like to incorporate statistical significance testing to see the significance of each permutation member individually, and then as a group. Would a paired t-test of the ensemble mean of the pertubation members (3 model runs) vs. the control member (1 model run) be an acceptable approach to testing significance of the fraction skill scores here?

As for the two dimensional data, the only approach I have seen done in other related research work is bootstrap resampling, but I'm not familiar with the approach and how it would work for two dimensional spatial data to test for significance. My background in statistics is limited to a few graduate level courses I have taken and none of the materials from those classes are providing direction to how I should proceed here, so any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!